# update sql (db) columns based on results from website

Tags: html, sql, client-server, server-side

I am new to the SQL world.
I have a big database from which I extract some queries and put them on a webpage (HTML based).

I would like to have the user fill a form, for every query that is displayed on the page, with (14) questions (same questions for all the queries).

every question should represent a specific column in the query, and should be updated according to the input of the user.

I'm stuck at the part of updating the desired columns for every query, and not sure how it should be done. specifically I'm not sure how I "connect" between the webpage and the sql.

What i have now is a big .db file from which I intend to extract my desired queries to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically have the html generated by a scripting language, such as php. So you would have some html to start a table, and draw the header line, then you would have the php to do a query on your database, and then loop over the result of your query. So something vaguely like:

```
function foo($mysqli)
{
  $query = "SELECT acolumn, anothercolumn "
          ." FROM mytable";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
?>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A Column</td>
        <td>Another Column</td>
      </tr>
<?php
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        echo "  <tr>\n"
            ."    <td>".$row["acolumn"]."</td>\n"
            ."    <td>".$row["anothercolumn"]."</td>\n"
            ."  </tr>\n"
            ;
      }    
?>
    </table>
<?php
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<p>No rows returned</p>";
  }
}
```

Now, how you get that `$mysqli` connected to your database, and how you let people log into your site to get access to the database, is a whole other question. Google can help. I suggest
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
as one possible way into that.

Comment: I oppose the term "scripting language", except when it denotes shell language (e.g. bash)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
How is it different if i'm trying to do it on python?

Comment: @Elazar - yes, that's a reasonable point. I wanted to distinguish a programming language, such as php, from a markup language such as html. Maybe "programming" would be a better word than "scripting"?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer: If you can write python well enough to read your database and to output html that will show a table with the results, then I would imagine your biggest challenge would be to configure your http server to run python. That shouldn't be difficult, and may already be available depending on where and how your page is hosted.